# Solution to Fredholm equation of the second type with symmetric Gaussian kernal

Tags: integral-equations, gaussian-integral

Is something known about the solution to Fredholm equations of the 2nd type of the following form:

$\displaystyle f(x) = g(x) + \int_{-k}^k f(y) h(x-y) dy$

where $f: [-k, k] \to \mathbb{R}$, $g(x)$ is an even function, and

$\displaystyle h(x - y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(x-y)^2/2}$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ Tf(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-k}^k f(y) e^{-(x-y)^2/2}\; dy $$
so your integral equation is $(I-T) f = g$.
Since $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-k}^k e^{-(x-y)^2/2}\; dx \le \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-k}^k e^{-x^2/2}\; dx  < 1$$
(call the middle integral $R$), we have
$$ \|Tf\|_\infty \le R \|f\|_\infty$$
Thus $I - T$ is invertible on $C[-k,k]$: there is a unique continuous solution
$$ f = (I - T)^{-1} g = \sum_{i=0}^\infty T^i g$$